# VLOOKUP() with repeated values

Tags: bash, awk, vlookup

I am dealing with some typicall VLOOKUP problem, but rather difficult due to repeated rows...

I have two files such as:

File 1

```
transcript1     miR1
transcript1     miR2
transcript2     miR5
transcript2     miR4 
transcript2     miR1
transcript2     miR2
transcript3     miR5
transcript4     miR2
```

File 2

```
transcript1     gene1
transcript2     gene1
transcript3     gene2
transcript4     gene2
```

I want to asign gene names to transcripts in the File 1, according to File 2, to obtain the following:

```
transcript1     miR1    gene1
transcript1     miR2    gene1
transcript2     miR5    gene1
transcript2     miR4    gene1
transcript2     miR1    gene1
transcript2     miR2    gene1
transcript3     miR5    gene2
transcript4     miR2    gene2
```

I tipically perform this task by using the VLOOKUP() function from OpenOffice or Excel, pasting the file2 into file1 spreadsheet.

But this function does not seem to work with repeated rows in the looking matrix (column 1 of file1)...

Does anyone know a way to do this? Seems simple but could not figure it out...

Any AWK, BASH, Excel/OpenOffice way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the issue. File 2 has unique values so you should not have any problem with it. The problem may accure in the other direction - if you will try to get the column 2 data from file 1 to file 2 you'll get the first instance of 'transcript#'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work whether your input files are sorted or not:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} {print $0, a[$1]}' file2 file1
transcript1     miR1 gene1
transcript1     miR2 gene1
transcript2     miR5 gene1
transcript2     miR4 gene1
transcript2     miR1 gene1
transcript2     miR2 gene1
transcript3     miR5 gene2
transcript4     miR2 gene2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [join](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/join.1.html):

```
join file1 file2
```

Output (based on your sample input):

```
transcript1 miR1 gene1
transcript1 miR2 gene1
transcript2 miR5 gene1
transcript2 miR4 gene1
transcript2 miR1 gene1
transcript2 miR2 gene1
transcript3 miR5 gene2
transcript4 miR2 gene2
```

Important: both files must be sorted for `join` to work.
Unsorted files can be sorted on the fly:

```
join <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

If your shell does not support command substitution, you can use temporary intermediate files:

```
sort file1 > sorted1
sort file2 > sorted2
join sorted1 sorted2
```